# Using pd.Dataframe.replace with an apply function as the replace value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several dataframes that have mixed in some columns with dates in this ASP.NET format "/Date(1239018869048)/". I've figured out how to parse this into python's datetime format for a given column. However I would like to put this logic into a function so that I can pass it any dataframe and have it replace all the dates that it finds that match a regex using pd.Dataframe.replace.

something like:

```
def pretty_dates():
    #Messy logic here

df.replace(to_replace=r'\/Date(d+)', value=pretty_dates(df), regex=True)
```

Problem with this is that the df that is being passed to pretty_dates is the whole dataframe not just the cell that is needed to be replaced.

So the concept I'm trying to figure out is if there is a way that the value that should be replaced when using df.replace can be a function instead of a static value.

Thank you so much in advance

***EDIT***
To try to add some clarity, I have many columns in a dataframe, over a hundred that contain this date format. I would like not to list out every single column that has a date. Is there a way to apply the function the clean my dates across all the columns in my dataset? So I do not want to clean 1 column but all the hundreds of columns of my dataframe.

Comment: How are you creating the dataframe to start with? Are you using `pd.read_*()`? You might find you can add the date parsing at the point of importing the data

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can use regex to do this in one step, but here is how to apply it to the whole column at once:

```
df = pd.Series(['/Date(1239018869048)/',
                '/Date(1239018869048)/'],dtype=str)

df = df.str.replace('\/Date\(', '')
df = df.str.replace('\)\/', '')
print(df)

    0    1239018869048
    1    1239018869048
    dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need to apply custom function to selected cells in specified column. Hope, that the following example helps you:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['one', 'two', 'three']})
selection = df.x.str.contains('t', regex=True) # put your regexp here
df.loc[selection, 'x'] = df.loc[selection, 'x'].map(lambda x: x+x) # do some logic instead
```

You can apply this procedure to all columns of the df in a loop:

```
for col in df.columns:
    selection = df.loc[:, col].str.contains('t', regex=True) # put your regexp here
    df.loc[selection, col] = df.loc[selection, col].map(lambda x: x+x) # do some logic instead
```

Comment: Thank you, however in my case  I don't know the column names with this date format in it ahead of time. It's a dataframe with hundreds of different columns some are dates, some are not. I'm trying to apply this replace procedure across all columns. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use applymap and re.
Like this:

```
import re

def pretty_dates(s):
    return s[3:]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": ["/Date1239018869048", "1.1.1.2", "abc"],
        "b": ["/Date29048", "b", "abc"],
    }
)
regex = r"\/Date(\d+)"
df.applymap(
    lambda x: pretty_dates(re.search(regex, x).group(1)) if re.search(regex, x) else x
)
```